# MPMoviePlayerController: Not playing video

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to use the MPMoviePlayerController to play a locally saved video however it is not working.

Here's my source:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

CGRect frame = self.movieView.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointZero;

self.moviePlayer.view.frame = frame;

self.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay         = NO;
self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay        = NO;
self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType       = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
self.moviePlayer.scalingMode           = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle          = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
self.moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

[self.movieView addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

It **does** work when I have a URL like "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=2C7D89F6-2211-4920-A842-30D773B075D6&ext=MOV" but when I have a URL like "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1454.mp4" it doesn't work.

I'm using the below code to get the users latest video and play it in the player:

```
- (void)mostRecentVideo:(void (^)(NSURL *url))completion
{
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];

PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:fetchOptions];
PHAsset *lastAsset = [fetchResult lastObject];

PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [PHVideoRequestOptions new];
options.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeMediumQualityFormat;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:lastAsset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
    if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]])
        completion(((AVURLAsset *)asset).URL);
}];
}
```

Comment: how did you get url in self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

Comment: The mostRecentVideo function is where I get it, the first time I use the UIImagePickerController to get it

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What's the behaviour?

Comment: @gabbler basically the video just doesn't show up. It just shows a black screen, or keeps the last video that was there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same code worked for me, I used it like this. Since getting the url is an asynchronous operation, it is a must to update the UI on the main queue. Just put the code in `viewDidAppear` and try again.

```
[self mostRecentVideo:^(NSURL *url){
    NSLog(@"did play!, url is %@",url);
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointZero;

    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = frame;

    self.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay         = NO;
    self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay        = NO;
    self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType       = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    self.moviePlayer.scalingMode           = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle          = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    self.moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    });
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}];
```

Comment: I have tried above code but it's appearing a blank screen! I can hear sound but not seen the video!

Comment: @kb920, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use `NSUrl *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];` for `url` in

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

But with filePath like: `file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1454.mp4` 
you must use :

```
NSUrl *url =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

See [NSUrl Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html)

Comment: The URL I'm using is '((AVURLAsset *)asset).URL' and that's what isn't working. Should I convert it to a string or something?

Comment: is file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1454.mp4 result (AVURLAsset *)asset).URL too ?

Comment: Yes it is, they're both NSURL's

Answer (score 0):

I made a some change in your code and put movie player code in PHImageManager block and its working for me.

```
      [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:lastAsset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
            if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]])
                NSLog(@"%@",((AVURLAsset *)asset).URL);

            AVURLAsset *assetURL = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:((AVURLAsset *)asset).URL];

            NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",assetURL.URL];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

            // Initialize the MPMoviePlayerController object using url
            _videoPlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                             initWithContentURL:url];

            [_videoPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

            // Add a notification. (It will call a "moviePlayBackDidFinish" method when _videoPlayer finish or stops the plying video)
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                       object:_videoPlayer];

            // Set control style to default
            _videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

            // Set shouldAutoplay to YES
            _videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
            [_videoPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

            // Add _videoPlayer's view as subview to current view.
            [self.view addSubview:_videoPlayer.view];

            // Set the screen to full.
            [_videoPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

        }];
```

Please check if it can help you...

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, but that source isn't working for me...is there a error logging for the player?